# drupal 8 render date field in node twig file

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8

Created a content type job openings and have a field called Posted On. Added date as 22 DEC 2016.I already created node twig file for this content type. Date field is not displaying even Posted on label is also not displaying. Made  the label as inline display.

```
{% set date_custom %}
    {{ content.field_job_posted_date}}
{% endset %}
```

#### {{ date_custom|date(format='j  F  Y') }}

I want to display this date field as 
Posted On December 22, 2016

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use:

```
{{ date_custom|date(format='m D, Y') }}
```

I'm not certain if that will work, but try it.